# SSRS % of Total to mimic excel

Tags: sql, matrix, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS matrix that  has a row group when executed shows fields off of a case statement. I need to add a column to SSRS so that it will give me a Percentage of the total

```
SELECT [Match?], activityID,
  case when [Match?]= 'yes' then 'YES' else 'NO' End as Status
FROM [dbo].[tblComp_MedPartCDBAMEnroll]
```

As you can see the case statement populates a yes no based on if the table has a match. I need a third column that is % of yes compared to total %of no compared to total.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxyOQ.png) Any help will be appreciated I have never had to do SSRS formatting of % when the column populates after the query runs

Answer (score 0):

SSRS has the CountRows function which will return a row count depending on the context of the expression.  Within the context of your row-grouped tablix, you can count the number of yes/no as well as the total number of rows in the dataset.

```
=CountRows("StatusGroupName")  /  CountRows("DatasetName")
```

Where "StatusGroupName" is the name of the group created on the "Status" field and "DatasetName" is the name of the dataset that this particular matrix is pulling data from.

Comment: what is a (Status Group Name) would that be the name of the match group?

Comment: It does not count it because of the group by status group name is there a way to count the rows using the group by